# UFT Jump to Step

Tags: uft

Within UFT Run Results View, I keep getting the following message blocking me from jumping to the line of code within UFT.

To use the (Jump to Step in Test) option, you must first open the test.

This option worked before....but can't seem to get it back.
Can anyone help?

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, (and I don't use UFT), but is the test you want to jump to actually open within UFT? Also, have you checked the UFT site and help documentation? There may be more information there.